# Bootstrap 3 adding gutters to the grid system

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm obviously missing something very obvious here but I want a 10px gutter between the bootstrap columns. Coming from ui-kit which has gutters by default, to turn them off you simple add the class uk-grid-collapse.

What is the bootstrap equivalent for turning gutters on?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKBjBa

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col1">
        <div class="div-content">col 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col2">
        <div class="div-content">col 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col3">
        <div class="div-content">col 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: solved your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define the colors to inner div. Here i have remove classes from parents and passed the classes to child div's

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <div class="div-content col1">col 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="div-content col2">col 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="div-content col3">col 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Because bootstrap has a default gutter space in `col-` classes so use them and define `background-color` to inner div's.

> The default gutter space is `15px` from each side left and right so you will see the default space of `30px` between the div's. If you want to change that space to `10px` just write you own css with desired space and overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using bootstrap class `container-fluid` , Please update your HTML with following :-

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <div class="container-fluid col1">
           <div class="div-content">col 1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="container-fluid col2">
           <div class="div-content">col 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="container-fluid col3">
           <div class="div-content">col 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a custom gutter width of 10px, you can do that by customizing the bootstrap with your value by using http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ or you can make your own custom class to overide it

Comment: yes I understand this but its no good if you're using the CDN version or if simply 'having a play' using things like codepen as you don't have the option to edit defaults within the framework

Comment: it's not CDN it will compile and download with your custom values or you can use SASS or LESS files provided with bootstrap to change the values with in frame work or you can write function or mixins for in the same

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely remove the gutter, Bootstrap 3 introduced `row-no-gutters` in v3.4.0:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-remove-gutters