# Bootstrap Grid Framework within Wordpress Theme Issue

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue with bootstrap grid framework within Wordpress. I am trying to create a grid. 2 Rows. First row is one column and second row is three columns with a little space in between them. The columns on the site are stacked as rows and not side by side. Bootstrap documentation says if you don't use something like sm-3 after col, then it will generate widths automatically.

Page in question: http://dev.dragonscaletech.com/our-story/

```
<div id="shoutOuts">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h1>Shout Outs!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h4>The TitanTough21 Foundation</h4><br>
      <p>An amazing foundation formed to find a cure for Li-Fraumeni Syndrome. Li-Fraumeni Syndrome is a rare genetic disorder that greatly increases the risk of developing several types of cancer, particularly in children and young adults. In addition,
        they work hard to help families pay their cancer bills.</p>
      <p>Learn more at: www.TitanTough21.org</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <h4>47 Films</h4><br>
      <p>A Digital Filmmaking Company based in Broward County, Florida.</p>
      <p>Really, a great company with great people.</p>
      <p>Learn more on Facebook: 47FilmsLLC</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <h4>Seagull Services</h4><br>
      <p>Assists individuals with life challenges by providing education, training, employment, residential services, community integration and support services.</p>
      <p>We are working with Seagull Services to assemble a manageable quantity of Back Scratch Scrubbers for us!</p>
      <p>Learn more at: www.SeagulServices.org</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs because you are trying to use Bootstrap 4 syntax with Bootstrap 3 running on your site. Those 2 don't mix well.

Solution: Replace `col` with `col-xs-4` in the second row and with `col-xs-12` in the first row.

Alternatively, load Bootstrap 4 files on your site.

P.S. Remember that both the `col` class in Bootstrap 4 as well as `col-xs-*` in Bootstrap 3 are non-responsive i.e. those classes define what happens on the smallest screens and you probably don't want 3 columns on the smallest screens. So, adjust accordingly.

Comment: P.P.S. Switching your WordPress site to Bootstrap 4 is probably a bad idea because you might have a lot of stuff that depends on Bootstrap 3 in your WP and/or plugins.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `col-md-offset-2` class ass [described here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-offsetting) in Bootstrap 3, if you are using Bootstrap 4 there are no more Offset classes, so you should use [auto margins](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#auto-margins) because Bootstrap 4 use flexbox

this certainly solves your issue

Comment: I'm trying to create 3 equal sizes grids that have a gutter or pad in between them so they aren't touching. I used sm-3 with margin around them. If I try to use sm-4 * 3 to get to 12, if I add any space it moves to another row on desktop view.

Comment: I put a border on to make sure everything lines up properly, it will be removed for sure.

Comment: you could let the columns touch each other, but you could add a internal padding, does that work for you?
Please check my updated answer

Comment: The background is white and the boxes are light grey. I am trying to make the boxes not touch so it doesn't look like one big box.

Answer (score 0):

Searched quite a bit on google and discovered the container-fluid class. Then I searched Stack Overflow and found this post.

[Bootstrap 3 adding gutters to the grid system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37457364/bootstrap-3-adding-gutters-to-the-grid-system)

I modified the code to this and got exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you to all that gave me more things to check out.

```
<div id="shoutOuts">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h1>Shout Outs!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h4>The TitanTough21 Foundation</h4><br>
        <p>An amazing foundation formed to find a cure for Li-Fraumeni Syndrome. Li-Fraumeni Syndrome is a rare genetic disorder that greatly increases the risk of developing several types of cancer, particularly in children and young adults. In addition,
          they work hard to help families pay their cancer bills.</p>
        <p>Learn more at: www.TitanTough21.org</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h4>47 Films</h4><br>
        <p>A Digital Filmmaking Company based in Broward County, Florida.</p>
        <p>Really, a great company with great people.</p>
        <p>Learn more on Facebook: 47FilmsLLC</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h4>Seagull Services</h4><br>
        <p>Assists individuals with life challenges by providing education, training, employment, residential services, community integration and support services.</p>
        <p>We are working with Seagull Services to assemble a manageable quantity of Back Scratch Scrubbers for us!</p>
        <p>Learn more at: www.SeagulServices.org</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```